# json appending json header to name when imported json?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to import a nested json file into a dataframe. I want it in this format:

```
year   columnA   columnB   ...
2018   ABC       123
```

but my Json comes in this format:

```
{'2000-09-30': {'accountsPayable': '1157000000.00',
  'accumulatedAmortization': None,
  'accumulatedDepreciation': None,
  'accumulatedOtherComprehensiveIncome': None,
  'additionalPaidInCapital': None,
  'capitalLeaseObligations': None,
  'capitalSurpluse': None,
  'cash': '1191000000.00',
  'cashAndShortTermInvestments': None,
  'commonStock': '1502000000.00',
  'commonStockSharesOutstanding': None,
  'commonStockTotalEquity': None,
  'currency_symbol': 'USD',
  'date': '2000-09-30',
  'deferredLongTermAssetCharges': None,
  'deferredLongTermLiab': None,
  'earningAssets': None,
  'filing_date': None,
  'goodWill': None,
  'intangibleAssets': None,
  'inventory': '33000000.00',
  'liabilitiesAndStockholdersEquity': None,
  'longTermDebt': '300000000.00',
  'longTermDebtTotal': None,
  'longTermInvestments': None,
  'negativeGoodwill': None,
  'netReceivables': None,
  'netTangibleAssets': None,
  'nonCurrentAssetsTotal': None,
  'nonCurrentLiabilitiesOther': None,
  'nonCurrentLiabilitiesTotal': None,
  'nonCurrrentAssetsOther': None,
  'noncontrollingInterestInConsolidatedEntity': None,
  'otherAssets': '1063000000.00',
  'otherCurrentAssets': '414000000.00',
  'otherCurrentLiab': '776000000.00',
  'otherLiab': None,
  'otherStockholderEquity': None,
  'preferredStockRedeemable': None,
  'preferredStockTotalEquity': '76000000.00',
  'propertyPlantAndEquipmentGross': None,
  'propertyPlantEquipment': '313000000.00',
  'retainedEarnings': '2529000000.00',
  'retainedEarningsTotalEquity': None,
  'shortLongTermDebt': None,
  'shortLongTermDebtTotal': None,
  'shortTermDebt': None,
  'shortTermInvestments': '2836000000.00',
  'temporaryEquityRedeemableNoncontrollingInterests': None,
  'totalAssets': '6803000000.00',
  'totalCurrentAssets': None,
  'totalCurrentLiabilities': '1933000000.00',
  'totalLiab': '2696000000.00',
  'totalPermanentEquity': None,
  'totalStockholderEquity': '4107000000.00',
  'treasuryStock': None,
  'warrants': None},
 '2001-09-30': {'accountsPayable': '801000000.00',
  'accumulatedAmortization': None,
  'accumulatedDepreciation': None,
  'accumulatedOtherComprehensiveIncome': None,
  'additionalPaidInCapital': None,
  'capitalLeaseObligations': None,
  'capitalSurpluse': None,
  'cash': '2310000000.00',
  'cashAndShortTermInvestments': None,
  'commonStock': '1693000000.00',
  'commonStockSharesOutstanding': None,
  'commonStockTotalEquity': None,
  'currency_symbol': 'USD',
  'date': '2001-09-30',
  'deferredLongTermAssetCharges': None,
  'deferredLongTermLiab': None,
  'earningAssets': None,
  'filing_date': None,
  'goodWill': None,
  'intangibleAssets': None,
  'inventory': '11000000.00',
  'liabilitiesAndStockholdersEquity': None,
  'longTermDebt': '317000000.00',
  'longTermDebtTotal': None,
  'longTermInvestments': None,
  'negativeGoodwill': None,
  'netReceivables': None,
  'netTangibleAssets': None,
  'nonCurrentAssetsTotal': None,
  'nonCurrentLiabilitiesOther': None,
  'nonCurrentLiabilitiesTotal': None,
  'nonCurrrentAssetsOther': None,
  'noncontrollingInterestInConsolidatedEntity': None,
  'otherAssets': '314000000.00',
  'otherCurrentAssets': '330000000.00',
  'otherCurrentLiab': '717000000.00',
  'otherLiab': None,
  'otherStockholderEquity': None,
  'preferredStockRedeemable': None,
  'preferredStockTotalEquity': None,
  'propertyPlantAndEquipmentGross': None,
  'propertyPlantEquipment': '564000000.00',
  'retainedEarnings': '2238000000.00',
  'retainedEarningsTotalEquity': None,
  'shortLongTermDebt': None,
  'shortLongTermDebtTotal': None,
  'shortTermDebt': None,
  'shortTermInvestments': '2026000000.00',
  'temporaryEquityRedeemableNoncontrollingInterests': None,
  'totalAssets': '6021000000.00',
  'totalCurrentAssets': None,
  'totalCurrentLiabilities': '1518000000.00',
  'totalLiab': '2101000000.00',
  'totalPermanentEquity': None,
  'totalStockholderEquity': '3920000000.00',
  'treasuryStock': None,
  'warrants': None}
```

Here's my code(it should work, it's using the site's sample token):

```
import json 
import requests
import pandas as pd

companyData = requests.get(url="https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/fundamentals/AAPL.US?api_token=OeAFFmMliFG5orCUuwAKQ8l4WWFQ67YX").json()
df = pd.json_normalize(companyData['Financials']['Balance_Sheet']['yearly'])
df
```

It results in:

```
2020-09-30.date 2020-09-30.filing_date  2020-09-30.currency_symbol  2020-09-30.totalAssets  2020-09-30.intangibleAssets 2020-09-30.earningAssets    2020-09-30.otherCurrentAssets   2020-09-30.totalLiab    2020-09-30.totalStockholderEquity   2020-09-30.deferredLongTermLiab 2020-09-30.otherCurrentLiab 2020-09-30.commonStock  2020-09-30.retainedEarnings 2020-09-30.otherLiab    2020-09-30.goodWill 2020-09-30.otherAssets  2020-09-30.cash 2020-09-30.totalCurrentLiabilities  2020-09-30.shortTermDebt    2020-09-30.shortLongTermDebt    2020-09-30.shortLongTermDebtTotal   2020-09-30.otherStockholderEquity   2020-09-30.propertyPlantEquipment   2020-09-30.totalCurrentAssets   2020-09-30.longTermInvestments  2020-09-30.netTangibleAssets    2020-09-30.shortTermInvestments 2020-09-30.netReceivables   2020-09-30.longTermDebt 2020-09-30.inventory    2020-09-30.accountsPayable  2020-09-30.totalPermanentEquity 2020-09-30.noncontrollingInterestInConsolidatedEntity   2020-09-30.temporaryEquityRedeemableNoncontrollingInterests 2020-09-30.accumulatedOtherComprehensiveIncome  2020-09-30.additionalPaidInCapital  2020-09-30.commonStockTotalEquity   2020-09-30.preferredStockTotalEquity    2020-09-30.retainedEarningsTotalEquity  2020-09-30.treasuryStock    ... 2000-09-30.totalCurrentLiabilities  2000-09-30.shortTermDebt    2000-09-30.shortLongTermDebt    2000-09-30.shortLongTermDebtTotal   2000-09-30.otherStockholderEquity   2000-09-30.propertyPlantEquipment   2000-09-30.totalCurrentAssets   2000-09-30.longTermInvestments  2000-09-30.netTangibleAssets    2000-09-30.shortTermInvestments 2000-09-30.netReceivables   2000-09-30.longTermDebt 2000-09-30.inventory    2000-09-30.accountsPayable  2000-09-30.totalPermanentEquity 2000-09-30.noncontrollingInterestInConsolidatedEntity   2000-09-30.temporaryEquityRedeemableNoncontrollingInterests 2000-09-30.accumulatedOtherComprehensiveIncome  2000-09-30.additionalPaidInCapital  2000-09-30.commonStockTotalEquity   2000-09-30.preferredStockTotalEquity    2000-09-30.retainedEarningsTotalEquity  2000-09-30.treasuryStock    2000-09-30.accumulatedAmortization  2000-09-30.nonCurrrentAssetsOther   2000-09-30.deferredLongTermAssetCharges 2000-09-30.nonCurrentAssetsTotal    2000-09-30.capitalLeaseObligations  2000-09-30.longTermDebtTotal    2000-09-30.nonCurrentLiabilitiesOther   2000-09-30.nonCurrentLiabilitiesTotal   2000-09-30.negativeGoodwill 2000-09-30.warrants 2000-09-30.preferredStockRedeemable 2000-09-30.capitalSurpluse  2000-09-30.liabilitiesAndStockholdersEquity 2000-09-30.cashAndShortTermInvestments  2000-09-30.propertyPlantAndEquipmentGross   2000-09-30.accumulatedDepreciation  2000-09-30.commonStockSharesOutstanding
0   2020-09-30  2020-10-30  USD 323888000000.00 None    None    11264000000.00  258549000000.00 65339000000.00  None    49327000000.00  50779000000.00  14966000000.00  46108000000.00  None    33952000000.00  38016000000.00  105392000000.00 13769000000.00  13769000000.00  None    -406000000.00   36766000000.00  143713000000.00 100887000000.00 65339000000.00  52927000000.00  37445000000.00  98667000000.00  4061000000.00   42296000000.00  None    None    None    None    None    50779000000.00  None    14966000000.00  None    ... 1933000000.00   None    None    None    None    313000000.00    None    None    None    2836000000.00   None    300000000.00    33000000.00 1157000000.00   None    None    None    None    None    None    76000000.00 None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
1 rows × 1197 columns
```

My goal is to get it into a format where it's the relevant columns of the dataset and then year is a row with all the values in the keys within that json like my sample above.

What can I do?

Comment: companyData is not JSON.  It has already been converted to a Python dictionary.  Try `df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(companyData).transpose()`

Comment: @TimRoberts first off - it worked! You are a genius!  Please submit a answer and I'll accept it.

second - I don't get  how it works, I'm calling it as a json ?